# Pass data from a function to table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been trying to create an app that gets a website data through a function ( func obtainData) and display some of the data on a tableView.

I have figured out the part on how to get the data from the website then make it as an array so I can use indexpath.row but I have not able to find out the way to pass on the data I'm getting to display it on a tableView.

Any ideas!

Thanks

Below is the code I wrote.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



        var recommendation = ""
        var recommendationArray = ""
        var delExtraTextArray = [String]()
        var urlRecommendationArrayStart = [String]()
        var urlRecommendationArrayEnd = [String]()
        var RecommendationStart = [String]()
        var RecommendationEnd = [String]()

        // need the var below to make the recommendations as an array to be used in a table view as indexpath.row

       var cellNumber = [String]()
        var cellTitle = [String]()
        var cellDetails = [String]()




        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            obtainData()
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self


        }




        func obtainData () {

            var url = NSURL (string: "http://www.choosingwisely.org/societies/american-college-of-obstetricians-and-gynecologists")

            if url != nil {

                let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        // to get all of the url content and covert them into string

                        var urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!

                        // to get to a specific contect seperated by a string

                         self.urlRecommendationArrayStart = (urlContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("<ol class=\"society-ol\">"))!

                        if self.urlRecommendationArrayStart.count > 0 {

                             self.urlRecommendationArrayEnd = self.urlRecommendationArrayStart[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</ol>")

                           // print(self.urlRecommendationArrayEnd)

                            // to check if there is any extra not needed text at the end of the recommnedations in the source page

                             self.delExtraTextArray = self.urlRecommendationArrayEnd[0].componentsSeparatedByString("<p><a")

                            if self.delExtraTextArray.count > 0 {

                                self.recommendationArray self.delExtraTextArray[0] as! String
                                self.obtainRecommendationTitle()

   } else {

                                self.recommendationArray = self.urlRecommendationArrayEnd[0] as! String
                                self.obtainRecommendationTitle()

                                // print("method 2 worked")

                            }


                        } else {

                            self.textView.text = "Sorry, couldn't get the recommendation at this point. Please make sure to download the updated version of the app"
                        }


                    } else {

                        self.textView.text = "Please check connection then try again"

                    }

                })

                task.resume()



            } else {

                self.textView.text = "Please check connection then try again"

                }




        }


        // to get the title of each recommendation

        func obtainRecommendationTitle() -> Array<String> {

            for var i = 2; i < urlRecommendationArrayEnd[0].componentsSeparatedByString("<p>").count - delExtraTextArray.count ; i = i + 4 {

                self.RecommendationStart = self.delExtraTextArray[0].componentsSeparatedByString("<p>")

                 self.RecommendationEnd = RecommendationStart[i].componentsSeparatedByString("</p>")

                self.recommendationArray = self.RecommendationEnd[0] as! String

                self.cellTitle.append(recommendationArray)

            }

            return cellTitle
        }




        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            return cellTitle.count
        }



        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

            cell.textLabel?.text = cellTitle [indexPath.row]

            return cell

        }
```

Comment: Show us some code and we will be glad to be of help.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you need help with. Often people have problems with the async nature of network requests and try to make an async call and expect the data to be there right after making the call rather than putting code to handle the data in the completion block.

Comment: I have added the code I wrote @sapopayne

Comment: The issue with my code is that I forgot to add tableView.reloadData() in my code. Thanks everyone for sharing your experience with me.

Answer (score 2):

You would pass it via the cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method.  This question is too open ended for a firm answer, but following along any half-decent online UITableView tutorial should do the trick.

A quick glance at this one appears to hit the basics: https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: FYI... `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not a `delegate` method, it's a `dataSource` method.

Comment: It's a method in the UITableViewDataSource protocol, which is what the dataSource property is.  I called it a delegate method because very often, any property that is a protocol type is, referred to as a delegate.  The table view is "delegating" the responsibility for cellForRowAtIndexPath to whoever is assigned as the dataSource.

Comment: In conarch's defense, objects like table views are a special case. A data source is basically a second specialized use of the delegation design pattern for something more specific. It's reasonable to call it a delegate method (although I would avoid doing so because you run the risk of confusing the distinction between the delegate and the data source.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to configure the contents of the table view cell with the data you want. Based on this assumption, you can use something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PUT_YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER_HERE") as? UITableViewCell {
        let stuff = yourArray[indexPath.row]
        stuff.some_property_you_want = the_value_you_want      
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

If you show some code or explain your problem a little better, you will get a better support from the people here on Stack Overflow.

**EDIT (based on your edit):**
Are you using a normal cell? 
The cell has the text field to put the string you want?
Did you define the cell's identifier, "cell", in the storyboard?
Did you connect the tableView outlet to the tableView itself?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell {
        print("ENTERED HERE!")
        let myCellText = cellTitle[indexPath.row]
        //what is the result of this print?
        print("TEXT TO ADD: \(myCellText)")
        //(...)
        cell.textLabel?.text = myCellText    
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

What is the result of these prints?

Comment: Make sure you perform tableView.reloadData() after you get the information loaded into the data that will be put into the tableView

Comment: Since we can't put code in the comments I edited my answer. Please check it and tell me what is the output of the prints listed in the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I'm using the default cell. I have defined the cell identifier in storyboard and connected thee tableview outlet to to the table view it self. When I'm using the " print("TEXT TO ADD: \(myCellText)")" you put int the code you have provided, I'm not getting anything on the log. even when I put in "print (cellTitle) under the "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell" I'm getting an empty array!

Comment: The issue is how to pass the new "cellTitle" array being created by obtainData(), obtainRecommendationTitle() to tableView

Comment: That is done is the function, in this line: "let myCellText = cellTitle[indexPath.row]."
Try to print the array "cellTitle" where is the print("ENTERED HERE!"). If it is empty, the problem is in one of the function obtainData() or obtainRecommendationTitle(), since these functions are responsible for adding information to this array.